# Is there a way to set tabIndex of an element to last in the tabIndex loop without assigning tabIndex to all elements in DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to customise the tabIndex order in a form of multiple input fields and multiple buttons. Since the elements in the form is dynamic it is a bit complicated to assign tabIndex to each element. 
As per the default flow, a button in the form comes in middle of the tabIndex loop, but I wanted it to be towards the end of the tabIndex loop. Is there a way to set the tabIndex of the button/element so that it comes towards the end of the loop ? will be great if this can be possible without setting tabIndex for all other elements in the form/DOM using jQuery

Comment: Have you tried giving the button a very high tabindex value? FYI, the maximum value is 32767.

Comment: in one way or another you will not escape the keeping of an input order, whether it is done directly on the tabIndex attribute or via JS to assign this value.

Comment: @terrymorse  yup, tried that by giving high index. Did not work out

Comment: @lime_pal See my recommendation and example below.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tabindex` to adjust the order of tabbed elements is frowned upon. As the [MDN web doc on tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) reads:

> Avoid using `tabindex` values greater than 0. Doing so makes it difficult for people who rely on assistive technology to navigate and operate page content. Instead, ***write the document with the elements in a logical sequence***.

Instead of reordering with tabindex, the preferred method is to simply reorder the elements.

So if there's a button that's ordered incorrectly, move it to the correct position.

An example:

```js
// move button with matching ID to last position
function moveBtn(btnID) {
  let wrongSpot = document.getElementById(btnID);
  wrongSpot.parentElement.appendChild(wrongSpot);
}
```

```css
/* optional styling */
#div-form {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 20rem;
}

input, button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.4rem 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Moving Button to Last Position:</p>

<div id="div-form">
  <input placeholder="input1" />
  <button id="wrong-spot">Button</button>
  <input placeholder="input2" />
</div>

<button onclick="moveBtn('wrong-spot');">Move Button</button>
```